# Error: Nested list behavior with each repetition of a for loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given this code:

```
import random

plusMin = [1000, -47, 1000, -250, 1015, -63, 1000, -563]

masterList = []
subset = [-125, 375, 250, 250]

for item in plusMin:
    if item > 0:
        masterList.append(subset)
        subset.append(1)
    else:
        masterList.append(item)

print masterList
```

Shouldn't the following output?

[[-125, 375, 250, 250], -47, [-125, 375, 250, 250, 1], -250, [-125, 375, 250, 250, 1, 1], -63, [-125, 375, 250, 250, 1, 1, 1], -563]

...appending a "1" to the subset with each repetition of the for loop?

Instead the output I get is:

[[-125, 375, 250, 250, 1, 1, 1, 1], -47, [-125, 375, 250, 250, 1, 1, 1, 1], -250, [-125, 375, 250, 250, 1, 1, 1, 1], -63, [-125, 375, 250, 250, 1, 1, 1, 1], -563]

which looks like the output from nested for loops. Why on earth am I getting four "1" appended to the end of subset with the very first item in the for loop?

Thanks!

Comment: You are adding a reference to the same list each time. Add a *copy* instead, see the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

```
masterList.append(subset[:])
```

When you do `masterList.append(subset)` you're passing a reference to the subset. So each time you're doing this, you simply pass multiple references of the same list and at the end when you do a print, all the `subsets` evaluate to be the final value of subset.

`subset[:]` makes a copy of the list at the time of append.

Comment: Thank you! This works beautifully. I don't quite understand why this works and my version didn't though... What do you mean by "a value reference"?

Comment: When you do `masterList.append(subset)` you're passing a reference to the subset. So each time you're doing this, you simply pass references of whatever is stored in `subset` and at the end when you do a print all the subsets are pointing to the same list.  `subset[:]` makes a copy of the list at the time of append, like a frozen copy of the value.